# Iterate complex custom annotation array

Tags: spring, annotations, javadoc

I have created a nested custom annotation. My code is here

```
@StatusCode(statusArray = {
          @StatusCodesArray(key="200", value="value is ok"),
          @StatusCodesArray(key="400", value="resource not available"),
          @StatusCodesArray(key="400", value="resource not available"),
          @StatusCodesArray(key="400", value="resource not available")
        })
```

Now I am creating java doc to show these status code through Doclet API([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)), but unable to interate the inner statusCodes value, however I am able to itereate simple annotation like this

```
AnnotationDesc annotationDesc = getAnnotation(method, "StatusCode");
ElementValuePair[] paramNames = annotationDesc.elementValues();
```

that return the value of StatusCode annotation, but how can I iterate StatusCodes value? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Pardon me but it's a bit backwards `@StatusCode` should be a code and `@StatusCodes` the array. Or maybe rename to `@StatusCodeArray` to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thanks Bart,I have edited this to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 3):

After trying a lot. I found the solution of this.There are two ways to iterate a array annotation type.
first if we are using Method API(java.lang.reflect) then it will be very simple, as Marius tells in his answer.

second is when we are using doclets(import com.sun.javadoc.MethodDoc api and others) then it is a bit trikier.First get your MethodDoc object and through this get AnnotationDesc object you will reach @StatusCode annotation in above question case.Suppose I have annotationDesc object of  AnnotationDesc API,then use following code to iterate &statusCodeArray annotation's value.

```
        ElementValuePair[] paramNames = annotationDesc.elementValues();
        AnnotationValue[] statusCodes = (AnnotationValue[])paramNames[0].value().value();
        if(statusCodes==null||statusCodes.length==0)
        {
            return statusCodeValue;
        }
        for(AnnotationValue statusCode:statusCodes)
        {
            AnnotationDesc anoDesc=(AnnotationDesc)statusCode.value();
            if(anoDesc==null)
            {
                return statusCodeValue;
            }
            String key=(String)anoDesc.elementValues()[0].value().value();
            String value=(String)anoDesc.elementValues()[1].value().value();

        }
```

You will get status code in key and status comment in value.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the Annotation as you're defining it in;

```
    // MZ: Parse the status code annotations
    StatusCode statusCodes = method.getAnnotation(StatusCode.class);
    if (statusCodes != null)
    {
        for (StatusCodesArray statusCodeArray : statusCodes.value())
        {
            // MZ: Do your magic
        }
    }
```

Gl !

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marius but I cann't use directly these Annotation interface(StatusCode,StatusCodeArray) name due to restriction problem.The annotation interface is defined in other module of project and and I am generating doc in any other module.